# How can I join between 3 tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, join

I have these relations

- Class (courseName, sectionNumber, classRoom)
- Student (name, ID)
- Takes (ID, sectionNumber)

How can I display the student names and the `courseNames` and `classRooms` that they're taking?

Comment: One can only guess. Takes.ID is probably a misnomer and supposed to be a student ID rather than a takes ID. It would be much better to name that column accordingly. Then, what is a section number? Do several courses share a section number? If so, how to say which particular class a student takes? And if not so, why is this called section number and not, say, class_id? So, start by getting the database straight. Use good column names that tell the reader what they are about. Then, what exactly is the problem? You want to join, so join. Have you looked up `JOIN` in your manual?

Comment: What DBMS are you using anyway? Always tag SQL requests with the DBMS you are using, because different DBMS have different SQL dialects, and what works in one DBMS may not work in another.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that there is a direct relationship between Takes.ID and Student.ID, the following query would return a list of Students, Course Names and Class Rooms ordered by Student, Then Course, then Class Room (all descending)

```
SELECT
s.name,
c.courseName,
c.classRoom
FROM
Class C
INNER JOIN Takes t ON t.sectionNumber = c.sectionNumber
INNER JOIN Student s ON s.ID = t.ID
ORDER BY s.name DESC, c.courseName DESC, c.classRoom DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT name.Student, courseNames.Class, classRooms.Class
FROM ((name
INNER JOIN CourseNames ON ........... = .........)
INNER JOIN classRooms ON ........ = ..........);
```

Comment: This looks a bit weird. You are confusing table names and column names here. And the parantheses make me assume you are using MS Access where the join syntax is very special. Not a good DBMS to learn SQL in my opinion. See Anthony Norwood's answer on how to write the query properly. (Albeit his query, too, is based on assumptions, as we don't know for sure how the tables are related.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    s.name AS [STUDENT NAME], 
    c.courseName AS [COURSE NAME],
    c.classRooms AS [CLASS ROOMS] 
FROM 
    Student s 
INNER JOIN
    Takes t ON s.ID = t.ID
INNER JOIN
    Class c ON t.sectionNumber = c.sectionNumber
```

It'll work for your job.

In this answer, first of all we joined 2 tables (`Student` and `Takes`) by `ID` column, after that we joined to the last table `Class` with using `sectionNumber`.

Now, you can select any column from these joined tables.

Comment: Brackets are not the standard delimiters for names. SQL Server uses them and maybe one or two other DBMS, too. The standard name delimiter working in most DBMS is the double quote. But then, why quote at all? You can simply use names without spaces, so they are not necessary (e.g. `s.name AS student_name`).

Comment: yes, it's not necessary, I usually prefer to use it like this, so I wrote it this way. The owner of the question can edit it for himself if he does not want to use it that way. I also didn't mention that it was necessary anyway